# Find the maximum line length in a given TSV colum

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to write a function that given a TSV file will get the maximum line length found in a column. I currently have this (working) function. However, I feel that I am missing something as this solution feels poor compared to solutions I have seen to find the maximum length of a file:

```
max(open(filename), key=len)
```

Anyway, I would love some feedback and would love some tough feedback.

```
def get_longest_item_in_tsv_column(filepath, column):
    '''
    Returns the longest line in a given file.
    '''

    longest_item = None

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f,
                                delimiter='\t')

        for row in csv_reader:

            current_item_length = len(row[column])

            if current_item_length > longest_item:
                longest_item = current_item_length
```

Answer (score 3):

This code can be recast into something that will be more efficient if all you are doing is scanning the file for the length of the longest line:

```
longest_item = None
for row in csv_reader:
    current_item_length = len(row[column])
    if current_item_length > longest_item:
        longest_item = current_item_length
```

Can be replaced with this:

```
longest_item = max((len(r[column]) for r in csv_reader))
```

So, what did we build here?  Working from the inside out:

```
len(r[column])
```

will return the length of the `column` in `r`. While

```
(len(r[column]) for r in csv_reader)
```

produces a generator which can return *all* of the lengths of column returned by csv_reader. And finally:

```
max((len(r[column]) for r in csv_reader))
```

returns the largest value of all of the column lengths.